# How to match digits only after a particular string, stop matching if non-digit is found - Python 27

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have huge string like this `dsdasdludocid=15878284988193842600#lrd=0x3be04dcc5b5ac513:0xdc5b0011ebb625a8,2`

I want to get the number after `ludocid`, only consecutive numbers.

I have tried this regex `(ludocid).*(?=\d+\d+)` and many more but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just threw a bunch of regex bits together... Let's work through that.

First, this is the correct regex: `ludocid.(\d+)`

(You would want to use it with `re.search` instead of `re.match`, by the way. Match requires the regex to match the *entire* string.)

---

But let's look at yours and see what went wrong and how we can get to the correct regex.

`(ludocid).*(?=\d+\d+)`

Imagine a regex as a function. You pass it the right things, and it gives you the appropriate result. When you wrap things in parentheses, you're saying "Find this and give it back to me." You don't need the `ludocid` given back to you, I'm guessing... so remove those paren.

`ludocid.*(?=\d+\d+)`

Now you've got a `.*`. This is dangerous in regular expressions because it literally says "Grab as many of anything as you possibly can!" Often I use the non-greedy version (`.*?`), but in this case it looks like we're just expecting a single extra character there. If you know the literal character you can use that, but to be safe I'll leave it as `.`, which says "Grab any one character."

`ludocid.(?=\d+\d+)`

Now let's go inside the parentheses. You've got `\d+\d+`, which says "Find a sequence of one or more digits, and then find another sequence of one or more digits." This equates to "Find a sequence of two or more digits." I don't think this is what you wanted (it's not how you described the problem, anyway), so let's reduce that:

`ludocid.(?=\d+)`

Okay, great. Now... what is `(?=...)` for? It's called a *lookahead assertion*. It says "If you find this string, *match things in front of it*." The example given in [the Python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) is:

> `(?=...)`
>
> Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.

Essentially this means that your regex will *never* return the digits. Instead, it looks to see if digits exist, and then it returns things from the rest of the regex. Remove the lookahead assertion and we're there:

`ludocid.(\d+)`

When you use this with `re.search`, you'll get the group you want:

```
>>> s = "dsdasdludocid=15878284988193842600#lrd=0x3be04dcc5b5ac513:0xdc5b0011ebb625a8,2"
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"ludocid.(\d+)", s).group(1)
'15878284988193842600'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `ludocid=(\d+)`:

```
s = "dsdasdludocid=15878284988193842600#lrd=0x3be04dcc5b5ac513:0xdc5b0011ebb625a8,2"

import re
re.findall(r"ludocid=(\d+)", s)
# ['15878284988193842600']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
ludocid\D*(\d+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1lf00m/2)

This will match literal `ludocid` followed by 0 or more non-digits and then it will match 1 or more digits in captured group #1

**Code:**

```
>>> s = 'dsdasdludocid=15878284988193842600#lrd=0x3be04dcc5b5ac513:0xdc5b0011ebb625a8,2'
>>> print re.search(r'ludocid\D*(\d+)', s).group(1)
15878284988193842600
```

Answer (score 1):

To match only the digits that follow, stopping at the first non-numeric char, try a positive look behind:

```
(?<=ludocid=)(\d+)
```

So:

```
re.findall(r"(?<=ludocid=)(\d+)", s)
```

The positive look behind will look for what you want, and only match if it is preceded by the 'flag' string.

**Note: **You may need to escape that second `=` sign like this: `(?<=ludocid\=)(\d+)`